# There are no apps to show. Hide this collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, external-sharing

I have been added as a SharePoint administration on an external tenant, but when i try to access the invitation link, i got this error:-

[image]

So what could be the issue

Answer (score 1):

As I said in this post: ["There are no apps to show." when someone add me as a SharePoint admin inside external tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1158085/34there-are-no-apps-to-show34-when-someone-add-me.html?childToView=1158383#answer-1158383), go to M365 admin center > Users > Guest users, select the account and mange product license, assign your account in that tenant with a license which includes SharePoint. You will see the apps on myapplications page then.

Comment: so you mean defining an external users as SP Admin will require a license ? unlike adding external user to a sharepoint site?